# Move object for a specified distance over a specific amount of time

Tags: c#, progress-bar

I need to create something similar to a progress bar but which gradually moves to the right of the form over time instead of percentage of completion. Both the time and the distance need to be specified when calling the move method e.g. I want the object to move 200px to the right over 10 seconds.

I just wanted to get some suggestions as to what is the best way to go about it?

I was thinking of using a timer and moving the object 1px to the right after every tick and then limiting the time by setting a limit to the ticks. Also, the object needs to look like a straight vertical line. I was thinking of using an image of a line, since I am more familiar with this than drawing images, but would drawing a line, then redrawing it constantly (like dragging) be a better approach?

Comment: I think using progressbar control will be a more better approach .

Comment: Is this WPF or Windows Forms?

Comment: Soooo, what's wrong with a `ProgressBar` control?

Comment: I just wanted to see what people thought was the best approach to do this, I see now that the question was a bit too broad and more of a discussion. My apologies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something quick and dirty:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    const int maxWidth = 200;
    const int maxTicks = 10;
    var currentTick = 0;

    // Create panel and add it to this form
    var panel = new Panel { Location = new Point(1, 1), BackColor = Color.Blue, Width = 0, Height = 5 };
    Controls.Add(panel);

    // Create timer that handles updates
    var t = new Timer { Interval = 1000 };
    t.Tick += delegate
    {
        panel.Width = maxWidth / maxTicks * currentTick;
        if (currentTick++ != maxTicks)
            return;
        panel.BackColor = Color.Green;
        t.Dispose();
    };
    t.Start();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, gave me a great start!